# Formatting namenode for Hadoop Installation

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

How to format Namenode of HDFS?
I have tried folliwing commands 
raj@raj-SVE15115ENB:~$ /home/raj/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

/home/raj/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
/home/raj/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
Why this is happening?

Comment: The command for user hduser is not working.....                     hduser@raj-SVE15115ENB:~$ sudo gedit /home/hduser/.bashrc
[sudo] password for hduser: 
hduser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
hduser@raj-SVE15115ENB:~$  gedit /home/hduser/.bashrc
No protocol specified

** (gedit:8250): WARNING **: The connection is closed
No protocol specified
Cannot open display:

Answer (score 1):

Command to format name node is

> hadoop namenode -format

But by checking the logs you provided, it seems that java home is not correct.

> Open .bashrc file
>
> Check the value 'JAVA_HOME' is same as where you have Java package, else change it to corresponding path
>
> also add java bin location to 'PATH' variable

Comment: I haven't changed the default `PATH` and seems to work. I also haven't seen instructions that you'd need to modify the `PATH` variable - `JAVA_HOME` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your Hadoop version.
With the recent versions, the command is `bin/hdfs namenode -format`. But according to my experience, at least these basic commands work just fine with the `hadoop` runner, even if it complains about deprecation.

Your problem is in the Java path. The system does not find your Java. First find out where your Java JRE is installed on the system and set the `JAVA_HOME` variable to point to it.

Comment: Modify the file in `$HOME/.bashrc` (if you're using bash shell, as I guess typically is). Set the `JAVA_HOME` to point to your Java folder. For example my file has: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr`.

Comment: Oh, and remember to logout and login to reload the .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

if your working with yarn or recent version, then use this command for namenode formating

> bin/hdfs namenode -format

and set `$java_home` with full path in `.bashrc` and `hadoop-env.sh` files

after this `format` the `namenode`